# MVC4 Postal - Accessing User Email Address searching by UserId

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a site where user A can book a lesson with a teacher, I then want to have an email sent to the teachers saying user A wants to book a lesson with you etc.

I have postal up and running sending emails without issue,
however, I don't know how to access the email address of the teacher to send the email.

The email address is saved as part of the built in UserProfile table. I have the teacher's UserId (as it's stored in a separate teacher table).

So is there a way to access the teachers email ,searching by UserId?

In any other table I would use t in db.Teacher.find(id) but this doesn't work within the Account Controller.

This was built using the default MVC4 internet website template using the built in simple membership. Let me know if more information is needed.

I've added the following to the AccountController;

private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

```
public ActionResult EmailNotification(int id)
{

    var user = from l in db.UserProfiles.Find(id)
                  select l;

}
```

db.UserProfiles.Find(id) however gives the following error;
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'LessonUp.Models.UserProfile'.  'Select' not found.

Which I assume is a result of it not being created through the entity framework?

Comment: u haven't given enough information for someone to help you. Are you using an ActiveDirectory or other membership provider? Did you load the schema for these records into your Entity Model? etc

Comment: Sorry, just added in some more information! The schema from the template is what the email address is saved in, I know how to access the email address of the user that's currently logged in, but don't know how to search for someone else's by UserId if that makes sense?.

Comment: this seems straight forward: search by the id. What error are you running into? how does your lambda search look? where are you getting the teacher id? are you certain it is valid?

Comment: Does that explain more what I'm trying to do? I usually would use a search by id, but it doesn't work/I don't know how to use it in the UserProfile context.

Comment: yes, very much. But if I understand you right, user.Email should be the value you're looking for

Comment: Sorry was trying to post an image showing the available options but I don't have enough rep yet. Perhaps it's just not possible to access to build in UserProfile table using Linq?

Comment: cant believe it. I've done it with every table known. including asp Membership provider.

Comment: I know it should work, that's why I'm asking the question :/ I'll keep trying different ways. Having access at least now to db.UserProfiles should hopefully get me somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query needs to be something like the following:

```
var result = from q in context.UserProfiles
     where q.UserId == id
     select q;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Sorry for all the confusion.